# Should I replace motor bike entire front braking system?

Tags: motorcycle, brakes, brake-rotor, yamaha

I own FZ25 motorbike which is 4 years old.

[image]

I felt front brakes becoming spongy for quite some time now. I bleeded brakes multiple times. Replaced brake levers, brake pads. I even changed brake wire from rubber to steel braided wire but still I don't feel the bite as it was before.

Are there any suggestions for what to do?
Should I replace entire braking system? If yes I don't want to go back to stock braking system or brake pads.

If I want to go with aftermarket or OEM are there any suggestions for complete system. My bike has 250cc engine with 100/80 17 front tire size and 280mm disc diameter.

`Note: It has no ABS`

UPDATE:

Brakes are spongy sometimes but now that it had rained for few months they have become hard and spongy (I don't know how to explain it). But brakes are not progressive for sure(like when you put finger on brake to make progressive halt not sudden halt). I have to press hard sometimes and suddenly it brakes.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The disk runout and caliper stiction needs to be measured and corrected if excessive.

Comment: Interesting. I had similar issue after putting LM dot4 fluid. Few friends said also similar remedies didn't work(bleeding loop, hose, cylinder change). For days I tried putting extra high pressure with the front lever(of course while stationary), like pulling the lever all the way in as much as my hand can, and doing this routine for quite some time. 
It worked!

Comment: @MinhajulAnwar i tried all the things i have even replaced rubber wire with steel braided wire but still nothing changed. It feels risky to ride breaks are unpredictable and have to apply to much of pressure on them. I'm thinking of changing to hydraulic front brake system.

Answer (score 0):

"Spongy" brakes are usually caused by one or more of several factors:

1. Air in the lines.
2. Worn or damaged brake lines.
3. Worn or damaged master cylinder.
4. Worn or damaged calipers.
5. Bad brake fluid, usually containing too much moisture.

It seems that you have addressed all of these issues and still have the problem.  So I wonder if you are misinterpreting the way the brakes are for "spongy".

Anyway, if you feel that changing out the entire braking system will help, then perhaps you should proceed with it.

Comment: Yes i have almost changed everything now only thing remains is callipers. But I do feel issue is something different

Comment: Generally I'd say that if the calipers are causing the problem either the pistons are sticking somehow or the fluid is leaking past the seals.  In the latter case there should be evidence.  I'm still not clear that there is an actual problem though.